# Alternative for selenium implicit wait

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the alternative for selenium implicit wait 'implicitlyWait(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)' as it has been deprecated.
I don't want to use explicit and fluent wait. The implicit wait was simple as we need to specify once in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit wait IS the correct replacement for implicit waits. Selenium contributors have stated multiple times that implicit waits are a bad practice and should be avoided.